# "on/off" check box in bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

<script>
    $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
</script>

</head>
```

All css/js files are linked correctly, but still I am getting a normal check box instead of a toggle button.

plz help...
:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the checkbox in a fiddle so that you may have a better understanding

Code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox" />
</span>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CDZt8/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your script is running *before* the markup is loaded. You should either do the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
});
```

... or place your `<script>` tags right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @user2781186 Then check if the selector is correct.